# making jdbc connection to oracle apex db

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle-apex

I am trying to connect to oracle apex database. I have ojdbc.jar in my classpath. Here is my sample code for this.

```
  public class ConnectionDAO {
    String database = "demo";
    String user = "myusername";
    String password = "somepwd";
    String host = "https://apex.oracle.com/"; // By default
    String port ="8086";
    private Connection con;

    public Connection connect() {
        try {

            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();

            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//" + host + ":" + port +"/"+database+"?user="+user+"&password="+password);
            //con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle://" + host + "/"
                //  + database + "?user=" + user + "&password=" + password);
            // Set connectionStatus
            System.out.println("Connected");

            return con;
        } catch (Exception E) {
            System.out.println("Not Connected");
            E.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }


}
```

But it is giving  the following exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: invalid arguments in call
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:208)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:236)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:414)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:233)
at com.lister.dao.ConnectionDAO.connect(ConnectionDAO.java:19)
at com.lister.quiz.Test.main(Test.java:8)
```

I am new to oracle apex. I browsed about it but did not get the satisfactory solution. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

The apex application is stored in the database.
You need to get the host and port referring to the database to make a jdbc connection. 
Usally default db port is 1521.

Comment: Thanks Giggs. I am new to oracle apex. Can you please guide me how can i get the host and port?

Comment: It's the host where you've installed the database. You can get it in the properties of your connection if you're using sqldeveloper. Or in the tnsnames.ora file

Comment: Hi @user3681970 : did you found the right credentials to connect to the oracle apex database ??